# CRTP compile detection with template composition

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm stuck with templates problems since few days and you solve each of my problem at a time so thank you in advance.

So I've a template (`tl1`) who care about a `uml composition`, and another template (`tl2`) wich is the `uml composed`
So my goal is to not compile if the `composed` object is not a `derived` of `tl2` and if `typename D` is not a `tl1 derived`.

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662995/make-sure-that-typename-type-is-a-derived-of-base) and the help of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417782/how-to-avoid-errors-while-using-crtp) I've got the following code:

```c++
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename C>
class tl2 ;

template <typename D, typename T>
class tl1 {
private:
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<tl2<T, D>, T>::value, "T should     inherit from tl2");
    std::list<T> mTs ;
    tl1() {} ;
    friend D ;
public:
    T & getTbyName() const ;
};

template <typename T, typename C>
class tl2 {
    //static_assert(std::is_base_of<tl1<C, T>, C>::value, "D should inherit from Database");
public:
    std::string getName() { return mName ; }
private:
    C & mC ;
    std::string mName ;
};

class cl1 ;

class cl2 : public tl2<cl2, int>  {

};
class cl1 : public tl1<int, cl2>  {

};
```

My problem is this compile very well and I would like not. 
I would like not compile because `D` from `tl1<D, T>` must `derived` from `tl1`.
And actually `class cl1 : public tl1<int, cl2>` is not correct but it compile. So why?
It doesn't compile if I change `cl1` to:

```c++
class cl1 : public tl1<int, cl2>  {    
    cl1() {}
};
```

I understand why it doesn't compile after the change, but I do not understand why it compile before.

The fact is `tl1` and `tl2` will be in library, so I want to perform all checks in the library. I will not have control over derived so I'd like to be sure that `implementation` is `tlX derived`.

Thank you for your time again.
Quentin

Comment: "My problem is this compile very well and I would like not." Why? Usually the issue is that something doesn't compile, and you'll want it to complile. "It doesn't compile if I change cl1 to:..." cl1 is already defined as you indicated, and this compiles without any issues. Your questions are unclear, and confusing. You need to clarify them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik is the description more clear now?

Comment: `std::is_base_of<tl2<T, D>, T>::value` checks if T is derived from tl2<T,D> but where are you checking if `std::is_base_of<Tl1, D>::value` (D derived from Tl1).

Comment: @Brandon I tried it but it doesn't compile I think it's because `D` is not known by `tl1` in `class cl1 : public tl1<int, cl2>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with doing what you are trying to do is cyclical dependencies. `std::is_base_of` requires a complete type in order to work as far as I am aware.

Your code has TWO restrictions in tl1..

- T must inherit from tl2
- D must inherit from tl1

In the end, it ends up looking like:

`tl1<T, D>` where D inherits `tl1<T, D>` where D inherits `tl1<T, D>`

In other words, D will never be defined because Tl1 requires the definition of D as a template parameter but D must inherit from Tl1 which requires it.

Now if you remove the restriction on D, then the following code will compile as it should because the first restriction is met. However, if you uncomment the static_assert in tl1, it will NEVER compile because the definition of D depends on the definition of tl1 which depends on the definition of D and so on.. and so forth..

You'd get an error like:

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'class cl1'
     struct is_base_of
            ^
note: forward declaration of 'class cl1'
```

Code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename C>
class tl2 ;

template <typename D, typename T>
class tl1 {
private:
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<tl2<T, D>, T>::value, "T should     inherit from tl2");
    //static_assert(std::is_base_of<tl1, D>::value, "D should inherit from tl1");
    std::list<T> mTs ;
    friend D ;
public:
    tl1() {}
    T & getTbyName() const ;
};

template <typename T, typename C>
class tl2 {
    //static_assert(std::is_base_of<tl1<C, T>, C>::value, "D should inherit from Database");
public:
    std::string getName() { return mName ; }
private:
    //C & mC ;
    std::string mName ;
};


class cl1;

class cl2 : public tl2<cl2, cl1>  {
    public:
        cl2() {}
};

class cl1 : public tl1<cl1, cl2>  {
    public:
        cl1() {}
};

int main() {
    cl1 a;
    cl2 b;
    return 0;
}
```

If you replace `std::is_base_of` with:

```
template<class B, class D>
struct is_base_of
{
  template<typename T> struct dummy {};
  struct Child : D, dummy<int> {};

  static B* Check (B*);
  template<class T> static char Check (dummy<T>*);

  static const bool value = (sizeof(Check((Child*)0)) == sizeof(B*));
};
```

It will give you the error:

`recursively required by substitution of 'template<class T> static char is_base_of<B, D>::Check(is_base_of<B, D>::dummy<T>*) [with T = <missing>]'`

Which in my opinion is much clearer as to what is happening.

**TLDR: You can't.**

Comment: Thank you for your very constructive answer (and your time). It is why `tl1` constructor is private. But I don't understand why `class cl1 : public tl1<int, cl2>` doesn't scream ...

Comment: @QuentinHuot-Marchand, generally it is not permitted to use incomplete types with standard library templates, and you may simply get undefined behavior if you do. There are a few exceptions, but, you can't expect the compiler to scream when you use any template with an incomplete type -- there is no way to program the template so that it generates an error if used with an incomplete type, or detects this at all.

Comment: @ChrisBeck I understand, I guess I have to deal with that. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Brandon You can, you just have to defer the check until the compiler knows enough about the types. See my answer [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35688195/2173029).

Comment: @Rumburak; Sure your code works because you change the requirements. The requirements does NOT state that "Value needs to inherit from cl1". It states that it needs to inherit from tl2 which is templated and that the second template parameter inherits from tl1. You're doing an inheritance from a subclass of tl1 and tl2 and neither of the subclasses are templated.

Comment: @Rumburak; http://ideone.com/zG4y6l it compiles even without "deferred_base_of" due to the change in requirements you made. Unfortunately, this is not what is in the question..

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for pointing out that `deferred_base_of` is not needed (I admit, I am quite surprised). I did answer the question of this post (it checks for the wrong thing) and the former post, though. The point is that deferring the check can break the cycle. See and play here: http://ideone.com/H4hm3O

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles, because there is nothing wrong in the static assert.

cl1 specializes tl1 with

`T` = `cl2` which inherits from `tl2<cl2, int>`
`D` = `int`

And then you verify that

```
std::is_base_of<tl2<T, D>, T>::value == true
```

So let's replace `T` and `D` here:

```
std::is_base_of<tl2<cl2, int>, cl2>::value == true
```

And that is correct.

In other words, your static assert is probably not checking what it should. As of now, I am a bit confused what you want to achieve. I'll post an answer to your former question, but you should seriously think about making your names clearer. It will help to comprehend what you intend to achieve.

After feedback from @Brandon, I guess you might be looking for this: http://ideone.com/H4hm3O